# Не могу запустить проект .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

Ошибка  AMM0000

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library C:\Users\ksish\Source\Repos\viknsagit\AutoShopMAUI\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\lp\130\jl\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
AutoShopMAUI    C:\Users\ksish\Source\Repos\viknsagit\AutoShopMAUI\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\AndroidManifest.xml 30
```

Пытаюсь поменять версию sdk на 21 но после ошибки он возвращает обратно на 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моем случае не было строчки указывающей минимальный sdk в манифесте по пути:

```
Имя_проекта\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
```

в этом файле нужно дописать эту строку

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>
```